# i am trying to build a game of chess and the tiles are showing up in the wrong place

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a game of chess in Console application and right now i am in the middle of building the board. the tiles are showing up in almost  the right places the top row is supposed to go:

white
black
white
black
white
black
white
black

however the tiles for the board i am creating goes

white
white
black
white
black
white
black
black

here is my code that's useful to what I need:

```
public static List<space> GetList(List<space> tiles)
    {
        //simple variable to use where ever i need it
        int k = 0;

        //arrays ment to keep track of the valuse of the x position and the y positions
        int[] minX = new int[8];
        int[] minY = new int[8];
        int[] maxX = new int[8];
        int[] maxY = new int[8];
        int[] minXPosition = new int[64];
        int[] minYPosition = new int[64];
        int[] maxXPosition = new int[64];
        int[] maxYPosition = new int[64];

        //holds the values for the space
        string[] spaceLetter = new string[8];
        string[] space = new string[64];
        int[] spaceNumber = new int[8];

        //holds values for the values of is white
        bool okToSwirtch = false;
        bool[] isWhiteSwitched = new bool[8];
        bool[] isWhiteNotSwitched = new bool[8];
        bool[] isWhite = new bool[64];

        //sets minx at index 0 inorder to get the other values
        minX[0] = 2;
        k = 5;

        //leeps through all the indexes in minx and sets the value of minx at index i to the value of minx at index i - 1 increased by k
        for (int i = 1; i < minX.Length; i++)
        {
            minX[i] = minX[i - 1] + k;
        }

        minY[0] = 2;
        k = 3;

        //loops through all of the indexes of miny and sets the value at miny at index i the the value of miny at index i - 1 increased by k
        for (int i = 1; i < minY.Length; i++)
        {
            minY[i] = minY[i - 1] + k;
        }

        maxX[0] = minX[0] + 4;
        k = 5;

        //loops through all the indexes of maxx and sets the value of max x at index i to the value of max x at index i - 1 increased by k
        for (int i = 1; i < maxX.Length; i++)
        {
            maxX[i] = maxX[i - 1] + k;
        }

        maxY[0] = minY[0] + 2;
        k = 3;

        //loops through all the indexes of max y and sets the value of max y at index i to max y at index i - 1 increased by k
        for (int i = 1; i < maxY.Length; i++)
        {
            maxY[i] = maxY[i - 1] + k;
        }

        k = 0;

        //loops through all of the min x position indexes, and sets min x position at index i the the value of min x at index k
        for (int i = 0; i < minXPosition.Length; i++)
        {
            minXPosition[i] = minX[k];

            //checks if i is not zero and if it can be divided evenly by 8
            if ((i != 0) && (i % 8 == 0))
            {
                k++;
            }
        }

        k = 0;

        //loops through all the indexes in max x position, and sets the value of max x position at index i to the value of max x at index k
        for (int i = 0; i < maxXPosition.Length; i++)
        {
            maxXPosition[i] = maxX[k];

            //checks if i is not 0 and if it's divisible by 8
            if ((i != 0) && (i % 8 == 0))
            {
                k++;
            }
        }

        k = 0;

        //leeps through by all of the min y position indexes and sets the value of min y position at index i to the value of min y at index k
        for (int i = 0; i < minYPosition.Length; i++)
        {
            minYPosition[i] = minY[k];

            k++;

            //checks if k is 8 and resets it back to 0
            if (k == 8)
            {
                k = 0;
            }
        }

        k = 0;

        //same for max y position
        for (int i = 0; i < maxYPosition.Length; i++)
        {
            maxYPosition[i] = maxY[k];

            k++;

            //same for max y position
            if (k == 8)
            {
                k = 0;
            }
        }

        k = 0;

        //sets all of the values of space letter to the values i need it
        spaceLetter[0] = "A";
        spaceLetter[1] = "B";
        spaceLetter[2] = "C";
        spaceLetter[3] = "D";
        spaceLetter[4] = "E";
        spaceLetter[5] = "F";
        spaceLetter[6] = "G";
        spaceLetter[7] = "H";

        //sets all the values of space number to the numbers 1-8
        for (int i = 0; i < spaceNumber.Length; i++)
        {
            spaceNumber[i] = i + 1;
        }

        //sets the value of space at index k to the value of space letter at index x and the value of space number at index y
        for (int x = 0; x < spaceLetter.Length; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < spaceNumber.Length; y++)
            {
                space[k] = spaceLetter[x] + spaceNumber[y];

                k++;
            }
        }

        k = 0;

        //sets all of the values for is white not switched
        isWhiteNotSwitched[0] = true;
        isWhiteNotSwitched[1] = false;
        isWhiteNotSwitched[2] = true;
        isWhiteNotSwitched[3] = false;
        isWhiteNotSwitched[4] = true;
        isWhiteNotSwitched[5] = false;
        isWhiteNotSwitched[6] = true;
        isWhiteNotSwitched[7] = false;

        //sets all the values for is white switched
        isWhiteSwitched[0] = false;
        isWhiteSwitched[1] = true;
        isWhiteSwitched[2] = false;
        isWhiteSwitched[3] = true;
        isWhiteSwitched[4] = false;
        isWhiteSwitched[5] = true;
        isWhiteSwitched[6] = false;
        isWhiteSwitched[7] = true;

        //loops through all of the indexes of is white
        for (int i = 0; i < isWhite.Length; i++)
        {
            //checks if ok to switch is false
            if (!okToSwirtch)
            {
                isWhite[i] = isWhiteNotSwitched[k];
            }
            else
            {
                isWhite[i] = isWhiteSwitched[k];
            }

            k++;

            //checks if k is 8
            if (k == 8)
            {
                //checks if ok to switch is false or true
                if (!okToSwirtch)
                {
                    okToSwirtch = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    okToSwirtch = false;
                }

                k = 0;
            }
        }

        //adds 64 elements to tiles with all of the stuff i created before
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        {
            tiles.Add(new space { minXPosition = minXPosition[i], maxXPosition = maxXPosition[i], minYPosition = minYPosition[i], maxYPosition = maxYPosition[i], spaceValue = space[i], isWhite = isWhite[i] });
        }

        return tiles;
    }
```

can someone help me figure out how to shift all of the tiles to the left a bit so it shows up how it's supposed to

Comment: Do yourself a favor and write a function that writes one character in one color(set) to one position! Even better: make the position relative to a frame rectangle!

Comment: @TaW why wouldn't the way i am currently doing it work

Comment: It should work once you get rid of errors (which I don't have time to look into.) But later you will need it anyway, don't you think?

Comment: When I ran your code, the "B1" value has the location of (2,2). Each subsequent tile in the "1" column is similarly moved up one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here:

```
//loops through all of the min x position indexes, and sets min x position at index i the the value of min x at index k
for (var i = 0; i < minXPosition.Length; i++)
{
    minXPosition[i] = minX[k];

    //checks if i is not zero and if it can be divided evenly by 8
    if ((i != 0) && (i % 8 == 0))
    {
        k++;
    }
}
```

When `i` is a multiple of 8, that should be the first item on the next row, but you don't increment `k` until after you've set the `minXPosition`.

If you change the order:

```
//loops through all of the min x position indexes, and sets min x position at index i the the value of min x at index k
for (var i = 0; i < minXPosition.Length; i++)
{
    //checks if i is not zero and if it can be divided evenly by 8
    if ((i != 0) && (i % 8 == 0))
    {
        k++;
    }
    minXPosition[i] = minX[k];
}
```

that should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is better way of writing Get List.  You code had too many errors to fix.

```
       public static List<space> GetList()
        {

            List<space> tiles = new List<space>();
            string[] spaceLetter = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"};

            const int X_BORDER = 2;
            const int X_WIDTH = 3;
            const int Y_BORDER = 2;
            const int Y_HEIGHT = 3;

            for(int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
            {
                for(int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
                {
                    space newspace = new space();
                    tiles.Add(newspace);
                    newspace.isWhite = (row + col) % 2 == 0 ? true : false;
                    newspace.spaceValue = spaceLetter[row] + (col + 1).ToString();
                    newspace.minXPosition = (X_WIDTH * col) + X_BORDER;
                    newspace.maxXPosition = (X_WIDTH * col) + X_WIDTH + X_BORDER - 1;
                    newspace.minYPosition = (Y_HEIGHT * row) + Y_BORDER;
                    newspace.maxYPosition = (Y_HEIGHT * row) + Y_HEIGHT + Y_BORDER - 1;
                }
            }
```